# Can a pointer be stored in std::mbstate_t type?

Tags: c++

I'm writing an implementation of std::codecvt facet that uses iconv. [This](http://fakedetector.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fakedetector/fakebase/src/codecvt_iconv.h?revision=1.10&view=markup) implementation stores a pointer to heap-allocated data in std::mbstate_t state argument.

Everything works fine, but is this code 64-bit compatible?
Is there a platform where a pointer size exceeds the size of std::mbstate_t?

Comment: The C++ Standard is remarkably reticent when it comes to mbstate_t. The type is in fact defined by the C Standard. I have re-tagged your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't the `codecvt` template take the state type as a parameter?  Can you just use a pointer type there instead?  I can't remember whether the various classes that use a `codecvt` place requirements on the state type.

Assuming that you can't just change the state type... on MSVC 2008, `mbstate_t` is `typedef`d as an `int`.  The standard only requires that `int` be larger than 16 bits and no larger than a long, so it's not 64-bit safe.  I guess you would need to store an index or key into some data structure instead of a pointer.

update:

The following compiles under VS2008, at least:

```
std::wstring const in = L"input";
size_t const buf_size = 256;
char* buf = new char[buf_size];
wchar_t const* char_next;
char * byte_next;
void* state = NULL;

typedef std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, void*> codecvt_t;
codecvt_t::result res =
    std::use_facet<codecvt_t>(std::locale()).out(
        state, in.c_str(), in.c_str() + in.length(),
        char_next, &buf[0], &buf[buf_size], byte_next);
```

Comment: Codecvt with state type different from std::mbstate_t is essentially useless in terms of standart streambuf implemetations. Using another state type will force you to reimplement streambuf ancestors.